# Android Kotlin AAR - Where and how

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

I’m a iOS SWIFT developer learning Android development and used to creating Cocoa PODS, as a result of this I using Kotlin and trying to create AAR library files.

I’ve created a project and within the project added a seperate module, selecting Android Module as the type. This additional module contains the code that I want to reuse as an AAR library in other apps. The additional module includes resources.

So the app and module all build and function as expected but I’m struggling to find the AAR file. If my understanding is correct it should be in the Output folder of the addition module, is this correct. Theres no AAR file is there a specific option I need to enable or way to create the required file?

Final question relating to allowing an AAR file or library to have internet access, is there an example of where to add this and the correct syntax? Currently I’m adding the required values to the main project module but ideally they should be added to the resulting library.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. The `aar` file should be inside the modules's build folder. The path would be `build/output/aar`. Try `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` gradlew task in your project and check the module's output folder. 

Regarding Internet permission, you can define that in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the module like `<uses-permission = "android.permission.INTERNET/>"`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update, I'd assumed that the build / running the application on the emulator would create the appropriate AAR file, it clearly doesn't. I had to specifically make the library and then the file appeared.